# Why does copper(II) sulfate react with ammonia?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, thermodynamics, kinetics, coordination-compounds

We've done preparation of Tetraamminecopper(II) sulphate $\ce{[Cu(NH_3)_4(H_2O)_n]SO_4}$ using copper sulphate and 50% ammonia solution.
Initially, a pale blue color of $\ce{Cu(OH)_2}$ appeared with turbidity then after a dark blue color solution is obtained.
It is a substitution reaction Initially, 
**why formation of $\ce{Cu(OH)_2}$ is taking place ??**

Is initially NH3 acting as a base and ripping off the proton from the complex $\ce{[Cu(H_2O)_6]^2+}$? 
Then on the further increment of the concentration of $\ce{NH_3}$, it starts to act as Nucleophile??
My high school teacher taught me that acid-base reactions are always fast, so in this example is everything is about kinetics? What is the role of the thermodynamics? From where can I get a quantitative explanation with proper data?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29126

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66938/adding-non-stoichiometric-amount-of-nh3-to-copper-solution