# Reaction between copper II sulfate and ammonium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

The reaction between hexaaquacopper(II) and ammonium reacts as follows

$$\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^2+ + 4NH3 -> [Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^2+ + 4H2O}$$

Apparently it's known from physical measurements that the hexaamine complex $\ce{[Cu(NH3)6]^2+}$ is *not* formed? Why is this?

Edit: This isn't a homework question by the way, I'm genuinely curious seeing as the hexaamine complex is formed when ammonium is reacted with complex cobalt ions.

Comment: "Simply speaking, the missing $\ce{[Cu(NH3)6]2+}$ in aqueous solution can be attributed to the high concentration of water which is competing with ammonia for the coordination sites."

Comment: The six ligand positions are not equivalent. I think the best answer is this. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/29172/22102